# Have made an IOS style swipe mobile nav, trying to slide it in from the side but it disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

This is my code, it works for the desktop view, but on mobile the nav is there for a second then disappears. Any ideas?
I've made a nave that you can scroll left to right with your finger on touch screens, but it's not very obvious that that is how it works so I wanted to animate it in from the side of the screen when the page loads. This is as far as I have got. (I am very new to javascript)

```
<div class="whatson_nav">
    <div class"inner">
        <ul class="categories">
            <li class="selected"><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">theatre</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dance</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">music</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">exhibitions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">talks</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">student events</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>



.whatson_nav {
    background-color: #6e6e6e;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.categories {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 40px 0px 0 20px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


$(function(){
        $(".whatson_nav .categories").hide(0).delay(0).toggle('slide', {
                direction: 'left'
            }, 1000);
    });
```

I'm a junior front end and very new to jQuery, the jQuery I have chosen may well be completely wrong so please offer any help or guidance you may have!